# the document cannot be opened. it has been renamed deleted or moved with visual studio 2013 and mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I was getting a issue when I was going to open MVC4 project view.It was giving below error.

`the document cannot be opened. it has been renamed deleted or moved`

I have searched and found that after deleting .suo file. It can be resolved. I did same and issue is resolved but other issue has come. Now It throws object reference error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Any One have idea how to solve this. Please do suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Where you able to resolve it.

Comment: Try running VS as administrator: Shift + right click on VS icon.

Answer (score -2):

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This error usually occurs when a property contains `null` value or type mismatch. 
If your model passed list type value, then the view has to have the following line at the top. Or check if any property containing `null` where it does not allow null.

```
@modes IEnumerable<Example.ExampleViewModel>
```

Comment: sorry, but my question is not related to programming with MVC view. actually I am getting issue when I open View in Visual Studio 2013 on click on View.

Comment: Is the of the file(view) different then other view files icon?